# MacOS. Не устанавливается pip

Tags: python, macos, pip

Пишу :

```
python get-pip.py
```

Получаю ошибку:

> ```
> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
> Collecting pip
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/e0/be401c003291b56efc55aeba6a80ab790d3d4cece2778288d65323009420/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> Collecting wheel
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/10/44230dd6bf3563b8f227dbf344c908d412ad2ff48066476672f3a72e174e/wheel-0.33.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'
> Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
> ```

Тогда:

```
chmod 755 /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip
```

Получаю ошибку:

> ```
> chmod: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip: No such file or directory
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите [brew](https://brew.sh/index_ru) и потом выполните команду:

```
brew install python
```

Это позволит вам установить последнюю версию Python уже вместе с `pip`